# IndexError: list index out of range em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o input da configuração da comoda e output o numero de gavetas inacessíveis .

Eu tenho este codigo agora

```
configuração = []
lista = []
aberto = 0

gavetas = int(input('Quantas Gavetas ? -->  '))
print('Configuração das gavetas :')
for c in range(0,gavetas ):
    z = input()
    configuração.append(z)

for a in configuração :
    if a == 'o':
        lista.append('aberta')
    if a == '#':
        lista.append('fechada')
if not 'aberta' in lista:
    print(gavetas, 'todas estão fechadas ')
else:
    if not 'fechada' in lista:
        print(0,'Todas abertas')
    else:
        while len(lista) > 0:
            if lista[0] == 'fechada':
                while lista[0] == 'fechada':
                    del lista[0]

            if lista[0] == 'aberta':
                if len(lista) == 1:
                    print(gavetas-1)
                else:
                    if lista[1] == 'fechada':
                        del lista[0]
                        del lista[0]
                        aberto = aberto + 2
                    elif lista[1] =='aberta':
                        del lista[0]
                        del lista[0]
                        aberto = aberto + 2

 print(gavetas-aberto)
```

O codigo pode parecer meio estranho é porque já o refiz tantas fezes ...
Todas as vezes que rodo o programa começando por aberto 'o' ele dá o erro de

```
while lista[0] == 'fechada':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Já tentei fazer de varias formas mas não estou mesmo a conseguir resolver este problema !

exemplo de input

```
o
#
#
#
```

Output esperado

```
2
```

output

```
while lista[0] == 'fechada':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro aconteceu porque você está tentando acessar a posição 0 de uma lista vazia.

```
...

if lista[0] == 'fechada':
    while lista[0] == 'fechada':
        del lista[0]

...
```

Neste ponto do código, há um momento que `lista` será `['fechada']`; a condição do `if` é validada e executa o laço de repetição; como o primeiro elemento é `'fechada'` ele é excluído, ficando `lista = []`; a condição do laço será validada de novo e... ocorre o erro, pois não existe posição 0 na lista.

Fiz o debug do seu código e veja como ele é executado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Nota:** Simplifiquei a entrada, deixando a lista fixa ao invés de ler do usuário e adicionei um `print(lista)` na parte do código que dá o erro para você acompanhar o valor atual de `lista`.

---

A solução é bem mais simples do que isso:

- Se a gaveta está aberta é acessível;
- Se está trancada:

  - E é a primeira é inacessível ou
  - A anterior também está trancada é inacessível;

O código para isso é:

```
gavetas = ['o', '#', 'o', '#']

inacessiveis = 0

for posicao, gaveta in enumerate(gavetas):

    # Se a gaveta está aberta é acessível
    if gaveta == 'o':
        continue

    # Se está trancada:
    # - E é a primeira é inacessível ou
    # - A anterior também está trancada é inacessível
    if posicao == 0 or gavetas[posicao-1] == '#':
        inacessiveis += 1

print(inacessiveis)
```

Isso já resolve o problema para todas as situações previstas.

Você até consegue simplificar o código para apenas uma condição:

```
for posicao, gaveta in enumerate(gavetas):
    if gaveta == '#' and (posicao == 0 or gavetas[posicao-1] == '#'):
        inacessiveis += 1
```

Se quiser *ir mais fundo*, você consegue resolver apenas com uma expressão:

```
inacessiveis = sum(
    gaveta == '#' and (posicao == 0 or gavetas[posicao-1] == '#') 
        for posicao, gaveta in enumerate(gavetas)
)
```